# Convert a list to specific dataframe format

Tags: r

I would like to convert a list of the type:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
[[2]]
[1] 6 7 8 9 10
```

into a dataframe with this format:

```
1 1 
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 6
2 7
2 8
2 9 
2 10
```

Thank you

Comment: `stack(setNames(L, seq_along(L)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
L <- list(1:5,6:10)
gather(as.data.frame(L))
```

Answer (score 0):

if your list is numeric, this could work.

```
L <- list(1:5,6:10)
Data_Frame <- as.data.frame(c(1:5,6:10),1)
```